# Makefile for use with gdb

Tags: c++, makefile, gdb, g++

I need help configuring my makefile to use it with the GNU debugger. I am running it on debian.

I am quite new to makefiles and after going through similar questions I've tried adapting the answers of those to my code, but it didn't work out the ways I tried (probably because i don't fully understand the syntax of makefiles).

This is the original (shortened) makefile:

```
INC=-I include

all: libs poisson_solver

poisson_solver:
    g++ -o  bin/poisson $(INC) src/main.c\ src/problem_setup.c\ libs/timer_tools.o

libs: libs/timer_tools.o src/problem_setup.o

libs/timer_tools.o: utilities/gettime.c
    g++ -c -o libs/timer_tools.o $(INC) utilities/gettime.c

src/problem_setup.o: src/problem_setup.c include/problem_setup.h
    g++ -c -o src/problem_setup.o $(INC) src/problem_setup.c include/problem_setup.h
```

Comment: Pass the option `-g` for adding debug information at the moment of creating the objects.

Comment: Do you mean for example:
```g++ -g -o  bin/poisson $(INC)  src/main.c\
```?
This does not change anything when calling the executable

Comment: What is your exact problem? Describe what you do, what you see and what you expect.

Comment: I had an error stating ```Segmentation fault (core dumped)``` and i wanted to see which lines were causing it. I found the error in my own now and for non-runtime errors i get the line of the error so that should be fine for now

Answer (score 0):

Your `Makefile` has several errors, and in general contains more cruft than it should.

Here is roughly what it should be:

```
CFLAGS = -Iinclude -g
OBJS = src/main.o src/problem_setup.o utilities/gettime.o

all: poisson_solver

poisson_solver: $(OBJS)
src/problem_setup.o: src/problem_setup.c include/problem_setup.h
```

See [this section](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html) of the manual.

Comment: I tried it the way you suggested, but now i get ```recipe commences before first target.  Stop.```
I was able to get it running with my "faulty" makefile this time, i will just have to read up on the manual you suggested the next time I'm creating a similar case